# Jersey/Jquery HTTP communication and JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, http, post, jersey

I have some trouble making Jersey and Jquery communicate data in JSON format.
In the following minimal example always a HTTP 204 is returned to the calling JQuery client.

```
@Path("/path")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class Resource {
    @POST
    public ReturnData postSomething(@Valid Data data) {
      Log("success");
      ...
      ReturnData returnData = ...;
      return returnData;
    }
}
```

I use the following JQuery code and the error function is called after each post.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     url: url,
     data: '{"data": "data"}',
     dataType: "json",
     error: function(data){
          alert("fail");
     },
     success: function(data){
          alert("success");
     }
     });
```

In Firebug I see the following HTTP Request/Response with the setup described above:

```
OPTIONS /path HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.15.109:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: http://localhost
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Thu, 24 May 2012 16:10:57 GMT
Allow: OPTIONS,POST
```

At first I had tried a setup without contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" in the JQuery post which turned out as follows:

```
POST /path HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.15.109:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost/test.html
Content-Length: 104
Origin: http://localhost
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Date: Thu, 24 May 2012 16:08:55 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Length: 72
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

I'm thinking that client and server can't find a datatype they both agree on for some reason. I find it strange that the accept header doesnt include JSON when setting the contentType to be JSON.

The Log("success"); on the server side is never executed.

Can anybody point me into the right direction?

Comment: BTW: An Apache HttpClient test can post to and receive json from the server without issues

Comment: That's my problem, too. I spend a few hours trying every suggestion available but I couldn't get it to work. It seems that .ajax cannot convert its data to a JSON object, as it is expected by Jersey.

Answer (score 0):

The dataType parameter refers to the data RETURNING from the server, not the data being submitted.   I think you're assuming it's sending raw json when in fact it's evaluating the data you pass and converting it to a string using jQuery.param()  That data will be available to you on the `$_REQUEST`.  See [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Per the documentation, the data you send should be in a key-value string in this format:

```
key1=value1&key2=value2
```

or in a map using this format:

```
{key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}
```

Perhaps your extra quotes are throwing the map off?  I personally always use the key-value string as it seems to have fewer quirks.

Comment: Thanks!
Actually I want the server to return JSON. 
I was following the tutorial below, where they also send a plain json string as data instead of a key/value string or a map format.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jersey-jquery-177519.html